# STM32F100xx DR Register

Tags: embedded, stm32, cpu-registers, mcu

This register can be used as Read or Write data to UART. I saw some expressions about this Register,

The first one;

```
RxBuffer[0] =(uint16_t)(huart2.Instance->DR & (uint16_t)0x01FF);
```

What does  `& (uint16_t)0x01FF` mean in this code?

Secondly, how can this register understand to read or write difference?

Finally, I saw some other expression in order,

```
huart2.Instance->DR
UART2->DR
UARTX->DR
```

all these expressions have been used to refer UART2 is there any difference between them?

Comment: You would do well in future to post separate questions.  Here for example someone may answer only one of your three questions, or may not answer all three correctly or may not know the answer to all three, but could help on one or two.  Asking three separate questions means that the only valid an acceptable answers are those that manage to answer all three to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 2):

> What does `& (uint16_t)0x01FF` mean in this code?

The documentation of `USART_DR` for your part:

[image]

Indicates that it it has 9 defined bits `[8:0]`, despite the reset value only defining 8 bits - that is clearly an error, and is contradicted (both in width and reset value) elsewhere in the same manual:
[image]

The mask 0x1FF ensures that only these 9 bits are used in the presumably 16-bit `RxBuffer[0]`, and that bits `[15:9]` are all zero. Commonly, you would receive 8-bit data over a USART/UART but the STM32 USART supports 7, 8 and 9 bit frames.

9-bit frames are typically used to implement *single master/multiple slave* bus protocols, where the 9th (MSB) bit is indicates whether the preceding 8-bits should be interpreted as *address* or as *data*.

It is probably unnecessary to mask the high-order bits since they will be zero in any case, but the manual specifies them as "reserved" so it is an abundance of caution perhaps to mask them since it is not specific about what value you might *read* from them, only that you should not _*modify* them.

> Secondly, how can this register understand to read or write difference.

There are two separate *physical* registers - the RxDR is *read-only* and the TxDR is *write-only*.  As such both registers can have the same address since the R/W signal selects the appropriate physical register. This is clear from the USART block diagram:
[image]
Hardware registers need not work like *memory*.

> Finally, I saw some other expression in order,
>
> ```
> huart2.Instance->DR
> UART2->DR
> UARTX->DR
> ```
>
> all these expressions have been used to refer UART2 is there any difference between them?

Probably not - inspection of the code will tell you that.  Without seeing the code one cannot say for sure.  It depends on how `huart2.Instance`, `UART2` and `UARTX` are defined and/or assigned. `huart2.Instance` is clearly a variable that points to a UART instance and probably at some point assigned to a UART address either directly or indirectly. `UART2` and `UARTX` must be defined somewhere - they are likely constants or macros, perhaps assigned `USART2` which defined in stm32f1xx.h (a USART is capably or operating in both synchronous (bit-clocked) and asynchronous modes).  I imagine `UARTX` is defined in the code as an alias for a specific UARTto simplify modification of the code for different physical UARTS.

Answer (score 0):

1. In this case the bitwise and operation is used to set the upper 7 bits of the 16 bit unsigned integer that gets written to the DR register to zero, while leaving the lower 9 bits as they are. In this specific instance the UART is probably being used with 9 bit communications, or the 9th bit is used for parity or multiprocessor addressing. The upper 7 bits are probably described as “must be written as zero”. You should find all this in the reference manual for your microcontroller.
2. The microcontroller bus contains electronic signals which say whether an address access is a read or write.
3. All three are equivalent, the difference is where the pointer to the UART peripheral structure comes from. In the first huart2 is a structured variable which contains the Instance pointer to the peripheral structure. The other two have UART2 and UARTX variables which point to the peripheral structure.

If you want to learn how to use the DR register you should get the reference manual for your microcontroller and read the chapter on the UART or USART that corresponds to your peripheral. There may also be application notes which explain the operation of the peripheral in more detail and give examples.